# Why doesn't my link to my pdf work?

Tags: html, css, pdf, hyperlink

I correctly linked my pdf to my project and spelled everything right but when I hover over it and click it, nothing happens. Im not sure if its something to do with the positioning of everything?

```css
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      background: white;
    
    }
    
    /*----------header styles-------------*/
    #header {
      color: #D7DADB;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 300;
      font-size : 15px;
      text-align: left;
      width: 100%;
      padding-left: 3em;
      position: relative;
      height: 15%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      padding-top: 1em;
    
    }
    
    #header img
    {
     float: left;
     padding-left: 3em;
    }
    
    h1{
    width: 9em;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0.5em;
    color: #45CCCC;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    }
    
    #nav {
      width: 50%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      text-align: right;
      color: red;
      font-size:20px;
      float: right;
      padding-right: 2em;
    
    }
    
    #nav ul {
      padding: 1px;
    }
    
    #nav li {
      display: inline;
      padding: 38px;
    }
    
    #nav li a {
      color: #2C3E50;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    #nav li a:hover {
      color: #45CCCC;
    }
    
    /*----------hero image styles-------------*/
    #hero{
     padding-top: 25em;
     width: 100%;
     height: 30em;
     position: relative;
     z-index: -1;
    }
    
    #heroImage
    {
     top: 9%;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
     position: absolute;
    
    }
    
    #overlay{
     width: 34em;
     top: -5%;
     margin-left: 30%;
     z-index: 2;
     position: relative;
     clear: left;
    
    
    }
    
    h2{
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-size: 60px;
     float: center;
     color: white;
     opacity: 1.0;
    
     text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    h3{
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 300;
     font-size: 30px;
     color: white;
     opacity: 1.0;
     text-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #000000;
     text-align: center;
    
    }
    
    a.down{
     font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
     font-weight: 400;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #181b1e;
     background: #45CCCC;
     position: relative;
     padding: 0.6em 1em;
     font-size: 1.2em;
     -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    a.down:hover{
     text-decoration: underline;
    }
```

```html
    <body>
     <div id="header">
      <a href="index.html"><div id="leftHeader">
      <img src="assets/logo2.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:65px;height:65px">
      <h1>Amanda Farrington</h1>
     </div>
      <div id="nav">
      
          <ul>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#workJump">Work</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="notes.html">Notes</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div id="hero">
      <div id="heroImage">
      <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="trees" style="width:100%;height:10%">
      </div>
    
      <div id="overlay">
      <h2>Amanda Farrington</h2>
      <h3>Graphic Artist | Web Designer</h3>
        <a href="assets/resume.pdf" class="down">View Resume</a>                
    
      </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: The code seems correct. What happens if you try to type the PDF address in the address bar? Can you see it?

Answer (score 0):

It's the z-index -1 on #hero - it's basically making it under the body. Change that to 0 or remove it and you should be good.

Comment: I was writing the same, but about #overlay (z-index: 2). If you absolutely need them, then add a (z-index: 99) to `a.down`, to bring it in foreground.

Comment: Well, since it's parent is "under" the body any amount of z-indexing of that child won't really help. Removing that -1 is the way to go.

Comment: No problem - marking this answer correct will be thanks enough :)

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how to center it like the rest of the text, it doesn't seem to move then I change the positioning and margins.

Comment: [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente) - a is an inline element so you can't style it in exactly the same ways you can style block level elements. You could make it display as block and give it some extra styles to get it centered OR you could just center align all the text in it's parent element which in this case should be fine.

Comment: I just tried to use the navigation after getting rid of the z-index of -1 and the button worked but then the navigation didn't. is there another fix you could think of?

Comment: It's because #hero is overlapping #header. You need to clear all of those floats you have in the header/nav area so it that won't happen. The floats cause the #header container to collapse and have no height. [look at this fiddle to see it cleared](http://jsfiddle.net/dkw4wjko/5/)